# Use category name in Sitefinity blog URL

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/slavo-ingilizovs-blog/2011/10/19/custom_url_formats_for_sitefinity_content_modules) on establishing a new provider and generating custom URLs, and it works as expected. There doesn't seem to be a clear reference for what parameters can be utilized in the settings as the example given is very basic.

I want to use the category name of the post in the URL. I tried:

```
/[Category]/[UrlName]
```

but what I got in the frontend was:

```
http://localhost:60327/my-page/Telerik.OpenAccess.TrackedList%601[System.Guid]/my-post-name
```

I also tried

```
/[Category.Title]/[UrlName]
```

which just threw errors.

Anyone know how to do this, or better yet, a good reference for the parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible since the Category property is actually a collection (TrackedList).
In theory you would need one of the collection items, let's say the first one, and your URL expression would be `/[Category[0].Title]/[UrlName]`, but this is currently not supported by the expression parser.

Also, the idea of making the URL dependent on a complex (related) field is not a good idea. If someone deletes that category, they will break all your blog post URLs.

I would suggest you to create a custom text field for the blog post item (ex: CategoryUrl) and then you should be able to set the URL format to `/[CategoryUrl]/[UrlName]`. Make sure `CategoryUrl` field is required.